# How can I provide a SSH password to SVN on the command line?

Tags: linux, ssh, svn, authentication

In my case, I want to do a SVN checkout:

```
svn co svn+ssh://10.106.191.164/home/svn/shproject
```

However, I want to have the password in that one line, so that it doesn't pop up.

Comment: Just a quick warning - your username and password will be exposed to ANYONE with access to that machine.  Just a simple "ps -elf" command will show the full command line.  In general this is not a good idea security-wise, and why svn and tools like it prompt for passwords.  Not that you can't do it if you control who has access to the system, just don't want people to think they should do this in general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> svn co svn+ssh://username:password@10.106.191.164/home/svn/shproject

Comment: +1 for answering the question and not just providing alternatives (worthy though they may be).

Comment: @briealeida - I just wish it worked: according to the test in my [post below](http://superuser.com/a/585974/39752), it seems it does not work, as a password prompt appears anyways; the same post contains a solution with `sshpass` (which does work for me).

Comment: As said above, this doesn't actually work.

Comment: Expanded: it would likely work as long as ssh does not ask for a password, which it would in most cases.

Answer (score 16):

Given that you're using SSH, the preferred way is to use a public key for authorization, which saves the need of a password completely.

A guide for creating and installing the keys can be found [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/297/how-to-ssh-without-password/).

Comment: Of course, if you want your key to be really secure, you should give it a pass phrase. :/

Answer (score 7):

Infinitely better is to generate a keypair.  As your local user:

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa

(accept all defaults)

Then take the contents of .ssh/id_rsa.pub and add it on the remote server to .ssh/authorized_keys
Be very sure it is all pasted into the same line. Also be very sure the permissions of the .ssh directory are 600.

Then you should be able to ssh without being prompted for a password.

Comment: "The permissions of ~/.ssh on the server should be 700. The file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys (on the server) is supposed to have a mode of 600. The permissions of the (private) key on the client-side should be 600." http://askubuntu.com/a/46425

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using a password you might want to have a look at a private/public key pair and have ssh use that. most linux distributions come with easy to use commands to create such a pair. this would however require access ti the server side (once) to deposit the public key file in your user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

Answer (score 4):

```
svn co svn+ssh://10.106.191.164/home/svn/shproject --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username <username> --password <password> --no-auth-cache
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I *do* want to enter a password - I don't like relying on my password being saved somewhere; however, I do want to enter it *once* per set of svn+ssh commands; and often, you just want to do one `svn checkout` - and have to enter tons of passwords anyways. It is in such a case I'd like to type a password only once.

So, only answers by [@Boinst](https://superuser.com/a/380426/39752) and [@Marius](https://superuser.com/a/71479/39752) were relevant for my use case; unfortunately, they didn't help, as I couldn't get them to work. I wonder if the post authors themselves tried the commands out before posting them, as now I cannot imagine how they could work - here's a test I did locally on my Ubuntu 10.04 PC (and I break with Ctrl-C, each time I see the password prompt appear):

```
$ svn --version | head -1
svn, version 1.6.6 (r40053)

$ cd /tmp
$ svnadmin create myrepo
$ read -p 'ssh myself@127.0.0.1? ' PASS
ssh myself@127.0.0.1? [type _PASSWORD_, press ENTER]

## trying first with https://superuser.com/a/71479/39752 
# (specify in URL user:pass separated by colon)

## plain ssh - asks for password anyway:

$ ssh myself:$PASS@127.0.0.1
myself:_PASSWORD_@127.0.0.1's password: ^C

# svn - with just username, as expected:

$ svn co svn+ssh://myself@127.0.0.1/tmp/myrepo myrepo-wc
myself@127.0.0.1's password: ^C
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly

# svn - with password added to URL, asks for password anyway:

$ svn co svn+ssh://myself:$PASS@127.0.0.1/tmp/myrepo myrepo-wc
myself:_PASSWORD_@127.0.0.1's password: ^C
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly

# trying then with https://superuser.com/a/380426/39752, https://superuser.com/a/327822/39752
# (--non-interactive and --username/--password on command line)

# svn - asks for password anyway:

$ svn co svn+ssh://myself@127.0.0.1/tmp/myrepo --non-interactive --trust-server-cert --username myself --password $PASS --no-auth-cache
myself@127.0.0.1's password: ^C
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

As far as `--username/--password` on `svn` command line is concerned - that doesn't matter with `svn+ssh`, because it's `ssh` asking, not `svn`:

[svn - Subversion ignoring "--password" and "--username" options - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687/subversion-ignoring-password-and-username-options)

> The prompt you're getting doesn't look like Subversion asking you for a password, it looks like ssh asking for a password.

Additionally, as the log shows, `ssh` itself doesn't accept "`username:password@...`" in the URL - and so neither does `svn`. Why it is acceptable to use only username in the URL in `svn`, is probably explained in `~/.subversion/config`:

> ### (If the URL includes a username, then the hostname will be
>   ### passed to the tunnel agent as @.)

Notice *nothing* is said about `<user>:<pass>@<hostname>`.

Now, thanks to the page [Subversion over SVN+SSH on Debian](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/subversion-over-svnssh-on-debian.html), I finally realized there is a `SVN_SSH` environment variable used in `~/.subversion/config` for the (I guess) ssh tunnel; and that finally opens up the possibility to use the program [`sshpass`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) to handle the password in such a one-way manner:

```
$ SSHPASS=$PASS SVN_SSH="sshpass -e ssh" svn co svn+ssh://myself@127.0.0.1/tmp/myrepo myrepo-wc
Checked out revision 0.
```

Well, at least I'm glad I finally found a solution that works for me - hope this helps someone else, too,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the given switches *username* and *password*.

Refer [Command-line authentication](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.tour.initial.different-user).

Answer (score 1):

I think using [sshpass](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) (in Linux) is the best way to get this.

Install sshpass

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

Set the temporary environment variable

```
$ export SSHPASS=*yourpass*
```

Edit the svn config file

```
$ nano ~/.subversion/config
```

Finally comment out add `sshpass -e` to ssh line, before the `ssh` command

```
ssh = $SVN_SSH sshpass -e ssh -q -o ControlMaster=no
```